# Create Json file from Python dataframe with grouping on one col and making column name as key with unique values as a list inside the key

Tags: python, json, list, indexing, group-by

#Create the pandas DataFrame#

My data frame is like this

```
data = [[6, 1, "False","var_1"], [6, 1, "False","var_2"], [7, 1, "False","var_3"]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns =['CONSTRAINT_ID','CONSTRAINT_NODE_ID','PRODUCT_GRAIN','LEFT_SIDE_TYPE'])
```

##Expected Output Json##

I want to group by column CONSTRAINT_ID and the key should be natural numbers or index. LEFT_SIDE_TYPE column values should come in list

```
{
  "1": {"CONSTRAINT_NODE_ID ":[1],
        "product_grain":False,
        "left_side_type":["Variable_1","Variable_2"],
        
  },
  "2": {"CONSTRAINT_NODE_ID ":[2],
        "product_grain":False,
        "left_side_type":["Variable_3"],
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely not the most efficient solution. However provided a `df` in the format specified in your original question, the below function will return a `str` consisting of a valid `json` string with the desired structure and values.

It filters the `df` by `CONSTRAINT_ID`, iterating across each unique value and creating a `JSON` object with a key `1...n` and the desired values based on your original question within the `response` variable. This implementation uses `set` structures to store values during iterations to avoid duplication of values before converting these to `list` instances before they are added to the `response`.

```py
import json

def generate_response(df):
    response = dict()
    constraints = df['CONSTRAINT_ID'].unique()
    for i, c in enumerate(constraints):
        temp = {'CONSTRAINT_NODE_ID': set(),'PRODUCT_GRAIN': None, 'LEFT_SIDE_TYPE': set()}

        for _, row in df[df['CONSTRAINT_ID'] == c].iterrows():
            temp['CONSTRAINT_NODE_ID'].add(row['CONSTRAINT_NODE_ID'])
            temp['PRODUCT_GRAIN'] = row['PRODUCT_GRAIN']
            temp['LEFT_SIDE_TYPE'].add(row['LEFT_SIDE_TYPE'])
            
        temp['CONSTRAINT_NODE_ID'] = list(temp['CONSTRAINT_NODE_ID'])
        temp['LEFT_SIDE_TYPE'] = list(temp['LEFT_SIDE_TYPE'])
        
        response[str(i + 1)] = temp

    return json.dumps(response, indent=4)
```

Comment: I agree its not the most efficient solution, but thanks a lot for quick response as it solves the purpose